# CUDA Segmentation fault on cudaFree pointer to array in struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, cuda, segmentation-fault

I got a struct living on the CUDA device which contains a pointer to an array. Computations, accessing the elements and everything works fine but when I try to be a good boy and call

`cudaFree(my_struct->pointer_to_array)`

I get a segmentation fault. `cudaFree(my_struct)` however works perfectly fine. Is there something I am missing?

Please find the following minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cassert>

typedef struct {
  int n;
  float *arr;
} DummyStruct;

__global__ void check(DummyStruct *d) {
  printf("EL %f", d->arr[0]);
}

int main() {
  cudaError_t status;

  // create host pointer to dummy struct
  DummyStruct *dummy;
  dummy = (DummyStruct *)malloc(sizeof(DummyStruct));

  int arr_size = 32;

  dummy->n = 0;
  float *arr = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * arr_size);

  for (int i=0; i < 32; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
  }

  // allocate device array
  float *d_arr;
  status = cudaMalloc(&d_arr, arr_size * sizeof(float));
  assert( status == cudaSuccess );

  status = cudaMemcpy(d_arr, arr, arr_size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  assert( status == cudaSuccess );

  free(arr);

  // for some reason this should happen here and not d_sp->coeff = d_coeff ...
  dummy->arr = d_arr;

  // allocate and ship struct to device
  DummyStruct* d_dummy;
  status = cudaMalloc(&d_dummy, sizeof(DummyStruct));
  assert( status == cudaSuccess );

  status = cudaMemcpy(d_dummy, dummy, sizeof(DummyStruct), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  assert( status == cudaSuccess );

  // free host struct
  free(dummy);


  // check whether array access works
  check<<<1, 1>>>(d_dummy);


  // THIS causes Segmentation fault (core dumped)
  status = cudaFree(d_dummy->arr);
  assert( status == cudaSuccess );

  status = cudaFree(d_dummy);
  assert( status == cudaSuccess );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement:

```
status = cudaFree(d_dummy->arr);
```

requires dereferencing of a **device** pointer (`d_dummy` - which was allocated with a device allocator i.e. `cudaMalloc`) in **host** code.  That is illegal in CUDA.

Since you already know that `(d_dummy->arr) == d_arr`, one possible approach to freeing the embedded pointer would be:

```
status = cudaFree(d_arr);
```

A similar concept (dereferencing a device pointer in host code) underlies the comment here:

```
// for some reason this should happen here and not d_sp->coeff = d_coeff ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. The issue is that in my real code I don't have access to d_arr anymore where I want to do `cudaFree` (only in the example above). Is it possible to introduce a helper pointer and do cudaFree on that?

Comment: You can copy your struct (`d_dummy`)  back to the host, and then retrieve the pointer from that host copy.  Or at the point that you do `dummy->arr = d_arr;` you could add another line of code such as `float *d_helper_pointer = d_arr;` and then later do `cudaFree(d_helper_pointer);`  Nothing else occurs to me.  I can only work with the code you show or descriptions you give.

Comment: Indeed, copying the struct back to host makes sense. Works now, thank you!
I wonder if this struct thingy living on the device is considered okayish style at all ...

Comment: Using structs as kernel arguments is fairly common in my experience.  structs with embedded pointers can be a bit challenging, but you seem to have navigated most of it correctly.  If you only intend to pass 1 struct to the kernel, passing by value rather than by pointer may be simpler.  If you intend to pass an array of structs (AoS), then very often an SoA scheme is preferred over AoS, but we're getting far afield from your question here.  There are many questions here on the `cuda` SO tag that discuss these various concepts.